# Passing array of pointers as argument to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've written a piece of code but I'm not sure about how it works.
I want to create an array of pointers and pass it as argument to a function, like the following:

```
int main()
{

    int *array[10] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
    }

    testFunction(array); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
void testFunction(int *array[3])
{
     //do something

    return;
}
```

What I don't understand is the following. I declare `array` as an array of pointers, allocate memory to it by using `malloc` and then proceed to call `testFunction`. I want to pass the array by reference, and I understand that when I call the function by using `testFunction(array)`, the array decays to a pointer to its first element (which will be a pointer also). But why in the parameters list I have to write `(int *array[3])` with `*` and not just `(int array[3])`?

Comment: `array[i] = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int *))` should be `array[i] = malloc(3*sizeof *array[i])`

Comment: As for your question, you pass an array of *pointers* to `int` (with type `int *[10]`). Why do you think that `int array[]` (which indicates an array of `int`) would work as argument?

Comment: Need "pointer type" as parameter of testFunction because assign "address of array" to testFunction. array == &array[0] == address of first array.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. It is strictly pass-by-value.

Comment: "*the array decays to a pointer to its first element*" correct. And as the 1st element is a pointer to `int`, the arrays decays to the address of a pointer to `int`, which is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter of `type *` can accept an argument of `type []`, but not anything in `type`.

If you write `void testFunction(int arg[3])` it's fine, but you won't be able to access `array[1]` and `array[2]` and so on, only the first 3 elements of where `array[0]` points to. Also a comversion is required (call with `testFunction((int*)array);`.

As a good practice, it's necessary to make the function parametera consistent with what's passed as arguments. So `int *array[10]` can be passed to `f(int **arg)` or `f(int *arg[])`, but **neither** `f(int *arg)` **nor** `f(int arg[])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void testFunction(int **array, int int_arr_size, int size_of_array_of_pointers) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size_of_array_of_pointers; j++)
    {
         int *arrptr = array[j];   // this pointer only to understand the idea. 
         for(int i = 0; i < int_arr_size; i++)
         {
             arrptr[i] = i + 1;
         }
    }
}
```

and

```
int main()
{    

    int *array[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int *); i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    }

    testFunction(array, 3, sizeof(array) / sizeof(int *)); 

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int *); i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Evering depends on what `// do something` means in your case.

**Let's start from simple : perhaps, you need just array of integers**

If your function change only values in array but does not change size, you can pass it as `int *array` or `int array[3]`.

`int *array[3]` allows to work only with arrays of size `3`, but if you can works with any arrays of `int` option `int *array` require additional argument `int size`:

```cpp
void testFunction(int *array, int arr_size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
         array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return;
}
```

**Next : if array of pointers are needed**

Argument should be `int *array[3]` or better `int **array` (pointer to pointer).

Looking at the initialization loop (I changed `sizeof(int *)` to `sizeof(int)`)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    array[i] = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
}
```

I suppose you need 2-dimension array, so you can pass `int **array` but with sizes of two dimensions or one size for case of square matrix (height equal to width):

```cpp
void testFunction(int **array, int wSize, int hSize)
{
    int row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < hSize; row++)
    {
       for(col = 0; col < wSize; col++)
       {
           array[row][col] = row * col;
       }
    }
}
```

**And finally : memory allocation for 2D-array**

Consider the following variant of your `main`:

```cpp
int main()
{

    int **array;
    // allocate memory for 3 pointers int*
    array = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
    if(array == NULL)
        return 1; // stop the program
    // then init these 3 pointers with addreses for 3 int
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        if(array[i] == NULL) return 1;
    }

    testFunction(array, 3, 3); 

    // First, free memory allocated for int
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    // then free memory allocated for pointers
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention, that value returned by `malloc` should be checked before usage (NULL means memory was not allocated).

For the same reasons check can be added inside function:

```cpp
void testFunction(int **array, int wSize, int hSize)
{
    int row, col;
    if(array == NULL) // check here
        return;
    for(row = 0; row < hSize; row++)
    {
       if(array[row] == NULL) // and here
           return;
       for(col = 0; col < wSize; col++)
       {
           array[row][col] = row * col;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `int[3]` work as an argument type if you want to pass in an `int* [3]`?

Comment: @templatetypedef Of course `int[3]` and `int* [3]` are diffrent cases, but I explained from simple case to more complex

Comment: "check can be added inside function" is a half solution.  Either check `array` and each `array[row]` or do not bother to check any would be more consistent.